# Locating application files on the android system

Tags: files

I am a total novice regarding the android environment.

I need to locate some files related to an application on the android system. My goal is to find a private key that would be stored in file format, but any file related to this application could give me other clues.

This application has been removed from Google Play, and the author doesn't answer my email.

Based on the error message I (almost 100% certainty) think the app uses the open source library [CoPay](https://github.com/bitpay/copay). But I don't know which version of the library. It's a really old version, sure of it.

So I have looked at the old code of this library:

- it's written in Javascript
- it uses Angular.js

In the code I have seen so far, I don't understand where the private key that I'm searching for, could be stored. I'm gonna ask a specific StackOverflow question about that point I don't understand in the Javascript code, but that's another story.

At this point I am wondering:

- how does Angular.js and Javascript can run on an android system ?
- how to find the files related to this application on the Android system ?

For the moment I use Android Terminal Emulator to do some `ls -lRa > my.log` and explore the android system on my PC viewing the resulting search. But I'm lost in the 82000 files that are found.

Not one javascript file. No Node.js or npm mentions either. No mentions of Cordova.

I just don't know where to start.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `abd shell` and the `ps` command, I determine the name of the package of the application.

Then, the files related to an application are located in the directory:

```
/data/data/package.name/
```

But the files in here are not accessible unless you have root rights. Or unless you run `adb shell`, and `run-as my.debugable.app`.
Unfortunaly release application are NOT eligible for the `run-as` command.

Not possible to list files in such a directory with `ls`

So the necessary next step is to learn how to root an android phone.